# How to build against custom angular 6 library module with aot and barrels

Tags: angular

When importing a custom library generated through `ng generate library my-lib --prefix=my-lib` and then importing in the project, everything works smooth.

After creating a second module inside the `my-lib`, also reusing it in the app is not a problem.

However as soon as I try to build with aot it fails with `Please add a @NgModule annotation` for my custom module.

I use barrels in each folder of the libary to export the modules.

Answer (score 1):

In order to successfully build with aot, you need to specify the full path to the index of the barrel in the consuming barrel and not just the folder.

in `index.ts` instead of:

```
export * from './my-custom-ui-component';
```

it has to be:

```
export * from './my-custom-ui-component/index';
```

There is an issue about it:

See Issue: https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/917